# Attach to an Azure ShareFile using WinRM and net use

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, winrm, azure-storage-files

### Context:

I have setup an ARM deployment from the [201-winrm-windows](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-winrm-windows) in azure-quickstart-template.

- The deployment run fine
- I can access the VM using WinRM
- I can run a script remotely using WinRM

The problem is that I'm trying to setup a storage file on that VM. The [official documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/) ask to run this command:

```
net use <drive-letter>:                                       `
    \<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net<share-name> `
    /u:<storage-account-name> <storage-account-key>

# Result:
The command completed successfully.
```

### The issue:

- When the command is run locally (local powershell on the VM), I have a success message and the mount appear.
- **When the command is run through WinRM, I have the same success message but when I connect to the VM, I cannot access the mount.**

### My code:

```bsh
$resourceGroupName  = "resourcegroupname"
$username           = "username"
$storageAccountName = "storageaccountname"
$zone               = "westeurope"
$hostName           = "$resourceGroupName.$zone.cloudapp.azure.com"
$shareFileName      = "test"
$winrmPort          = '5986'
$storageAccountKey  = "......................"

$cred = new-object                                       `
     -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
     -argumentlist $username, $password

$soptions = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck

Invoke-Command                     `
    -ComputerName  $hostName       `
    -Credential    $cred           `
    -Port          $winrmPort      `
    -SessionOption $soptions       `
    -filepath      .\provision.ps1 `
    -UseSSL                        `
    -ArgumentList                  `
        $storageAccountName,       `
        $storageAccountKey,        `
        $shareFileName
```

And the provision file `.\provision.ps1`:

```bsh
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=0)]
    [string]$accountStorageName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [string]$accountStorageKey,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
    [string]$shareFileName
)

net use w:                                                     `
    \\$accountStorageName.file.core.windows.net\$shareFileName `
    /user:$accountStorageName $accountStorageKey
```

---

Note:

- my issue is similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/678773/how-to-persist-credentials-in-a-remote-powershell-session?newreg=8190dd98c39c427f84da745c41067296) but the author have no response.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot access the mount"? Is there any error message?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are hitting into in this case is that, WinRM runs as NetworkService. When you 'net use' through WinRM, the mount operation is done for NetworkService user, and you cannot access it through another user you connect to VM with. You'll need to ensure that the mount operation is done through same user context that you'll need to access the share as.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried what you've done but I can access the mount successfully. A small difference is that I connect to the VM first and then mount the file share, I didn't combine these two steps into one like you did, not sure whether this is the issue but just like to share with you and for your reference.

I uploaded a file in my file share and I can access the file share and get the file as below snapshot shows:
[image]

Update access from RDP:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. After adding the mount using a remote Powershell, can you access it from a Remote Desktop ? For me, the drive `Status` is `unavailable`. For your example, it seems you are testing the mount from the same powershell session.

Comment: @ThibaultDeheurles Yes, just verified through RDP, the share is accessable. See my updates.

Comment: I'm trying to tun the same command as you but I don't have the same results ... the drive does not appear in the explorer and a local powershell `net use` return the drive but in an `unavailable` status. Which version of windows are you using please ? Mine is WindowsServer2012_R2_datacenter.

Comment: @ThibaultDeheurles Mine is WindowsServer2012_R2_datacenter too, I just use the template you provided and didn't change anything. You mentioned "the drive does not appear", please try restart the server and see if it shows up. I met the "dosen't appear" issue too after net use and a restart solves it. And by the way, why the drive always stuck in unavailble? I am wondering whether the issue is related to the share itself. Maybe try recreate a file share? Really weird behavior..

Comment: thanks for help. Yes, I tried a restart too but it didn't add the drive in the explorer. I'm redploying another time to test on a clean machine.  If it does not succeed, I'll try with the exact same tutorial as you (I have done some setup in top of it but it should not interfer). I'll also try with new share file. Coming back after these differents tests.

Comment: From a new virtual machine, I have connected with RPS and run the net use. From the RPS, the drive is active and I can see the content. Then, with RDP, the explorer was empty and the powershell `net use` returned an `unavailable` drive. After the reboot of the VM, with RDP, I can see the drive in the explorer but it's inaccessible (with a red cross). Clicking on it ask for the credentials. After entering manually the credentials, the drive `status` turn to `OK`. Is your share a public one (it seems not as you use a key ...) ?

Comment: @ThibaultDeheurles So finally you are able to access the share successfully, glad to hear that. Re-entering the credential is the expected behavior after reboot, also you could persist your storage account credentials on the VM so that Windows will reconnect to the file share automatically when the virtual machine reboots, just run this command in Powershell: `**cmdkey /add:<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net /user:<storage-account-name> /pass:<storage-account-key>**`.

Comment: You can check [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/#persist-your-storage-account-credentials-for-the-virtual-machine) for details.

Comment: thanks for support ! Do you confirm that the `cmdkey` works through remote powershell ? Here is the result of my attempts: `cannot use cmdkey with PSSession`. You can see my post on that [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/1495) at `My tests with Powershell Remote` -> `Official Azure Storage tutorial`